# Permutation proofs

Tags: permutations, proof-verification

I have just started going though "An Introduction to the theory of groups" by J.J Rotman. I have questions above the following two exercises:

" The identity function $1_X$ on a the set $X$ is a permutation. Show that $1_x \alpha = \alpha 1_x$ for all $\alpha \in S_X$

**My Proposed solution** :

The identity map $ 1_X : X \to X $ is defined as : 
$$1_X(x) = x: \forall x \in X$$

Now if we have some $\alpha \in S_X$ then the product:
$$ \alpha  1_X ( x)  = \alpha ( 1_X( x) ) $$

$$ =  \alpha ( x) :\forall x \in X$$

and :

$$ 1_X \alpha (x) = 1_X ( \alpha(x)) $$
$$ = \alpha (x) : \forall x \in X $$

so $1_X \alpha  = \alpha 1_X : \forall \alpha\in S_X  $

Is this sufficient enough?

"For each $\alpha \in S_X$, prove that there is $ \beta \in S_X  $ with $\alpha\beta =1 = \beta \alpha  $"

Now obviously  $\alpha $ is a bijection  and thus  there exist an inverse and this inverse is a element of $S_X$  if we let $\beta = \alpha^{-1}   $  then the above is true. However I am unsure how to rigorously express this.

Comment: Your proof that $1_X\alpha = \alpha1_X$ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $y \in X $ there exists an unique $x \in X$ such that $\alpha(x) = y$ , so define $$\beta(y) = \beta(\alpha(x))= x $$ This is a good definition because $\alpha$ is bijective, and then you have to verify that $\beta\alpha = \alpha\beta = 1$

Comment: and $\beta(x)$?

Comment: I defined $\beta$ using the letter $y$, but it's the same

Comment: Matthew I answered, to me my answer looks rigourous

Comment: I am not questioning you part, but my part that I added

Comment: I think you should create a new question